# Get title bar height for a SizeableToolWindow .NET form

Tags: winforms, forms, height, titlebar, formborderstyle

I have already written at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396293/getting-correct-winforms-forms-border-width-when-changing-formborderstyle-from that .NET WindowsForms package has some problems with calculating the border size. Now I need to know how to retrieve the height of the title bar part of a form with the FormBorderSize property set to 'SizableToolWindow'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it seems overlooked this thing in the managed tools before asking:

```
SystemInformation.ToolWindowCaptionHeight
```

Comment: Figured I'd add a bit more information.

The fullpath is [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation] and ToolWindowCaptionHeight is a property of that object.

Comment: This is not the correct way of finding the height of the title bar. It only gives you the height of the title caption (text) in the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

I calculate a title bar heigh for any form, using the following, valid for normal forms or SizableToolWindow:

```
Rectangle screenRectangle = RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - this.Top;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And even if the form is hidden?

Comment: No, the form must be visible and not minimized, but you can calculate once at the beggining and preserve this value.

Comment: That's the problem - the form should be visible. I need to know this value before the form becomes visible the first time. And in the general case, I cannot cache this value because the user may change the window appearance (say switch from the Aero theme to the classic one).

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This is my way of finding the height of the titlebar in a winform. This also works when the form is hidden. Code is VB.NET.

```
Dim TitlebarHeight as Integer = (Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height)
```